# Why, after turning on a Windows 7 PC, the background was missing, history/cookies/cache were cleared, and all desktop elements were gone?

Tags: windows-7, virus, malware, history

So, there's a network of PC's with Windows 7 in them (one is 32bits and the other one 64bits). This has happened to 2 of those machines, when my client turns them on, all of the desktop elements are gone (shortcuts and files in the desktop), the background is black (I assume it's just missing), and browser data is gone (cache/history/cookies). Also, it seems to mess up keyboard keymaps, like you would've changed languages.

I've scanned it with both MalwareBytes and Avast, and they returned nothing (0 threats). Do any of you have any idea what this might be? I've searched online but found nothing.

I know this is very little info but there aren't any error logs or anything like that, it's very annoying to debug.

Comment: Sounds like a temporary profile was created due to corruption of the user profile

Comment: You're absolutely right, It appears it's recoverable, you just have to create a new profile and move the files there. [**source**](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-start/my-profile-is-not-opening-and-a-temp-profile-was/0ea823d6-97be-4416-a77e-fc2a66e406d2). Since you came up with it, would you like to answer the question so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can login with another working account, seeing if the problem still happens.  In this way, we can determine if it is caused by user profile.

How to repair domain user profile:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/14039/windows-7-fix-corrupted-user-profile